# error logcats on my android

Tags: android, logcat

what causes these errors I found on my Catlog app for android can anyone tell??

```
03-12 10:49:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7200.000000000
03-12 10:50:00.049 E/ThermistorObserver(379): stopControl !!! 
03-12 10:50:00.169 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7274.810000000
03-12 10:50:00.169 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7214.041000000
03-12 10:50:00.209 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7259.035000000
03-12 10:50:06.859 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7265.684000000
03-12 10:50:14.209 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7259.814000000
03-12 10:50:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7274.063000000
03-12 10:51:05.859 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7274.810000000
03-12 10:51:14.239 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7318.249000000
03-12 10:51:14.990 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7708.413000000
03-12 10:51:58.429 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7319.815000000
03-12 10:51:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7334.095000000
03-12 10:52:14.279 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7379.814000000
03-12 10:52:59.990 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7394.126000000
03-12 10:53:14.309 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7439.815000000
03-12 10:53:59.999 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7454.165000000
03-12 10:54:14.349 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7499.814000000
03-12 10:54:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7514.204000000
03-12 10:55:14.380 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7559.815000000
03-12 10:55:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7574.240000000
03-12 10:56:14.409 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7619.814000000
03-12 10:56:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7634.260000000
03-12 10:57:14.439 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7679.814000000
03-12 10:57:59.990 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7694.304000000
03-12 10:58:14.479 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7739.814000000
03-12 10:58:28.589 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 8100.000000000
03-12 10:58:28.669 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7768.492000000
03-12 10:58:29.409 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 7719.183000000
03-12 10:58:39.360 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 8100.000000000
03-12 10:58:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7754.346000000
03-12 10:59:14.519 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7799.814000000
03-12 10:59:59.989 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7814.371000000
03-12 11:00:14.539 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7859.815000000
03-12 11:00:59.999 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7874.389000000
03-12 11:01:14.560 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7918.259000000
03-12 11:01:51.889 E/ActivityThread(814): Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.helphub.provider
03-12 11:01:52.039 E/WallpaperService(379): WallpaperManagerService currSimId:1
03-12 11:01:52.679 E/ActivityThread(814): Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.helphub.provider
03-12 11:01:58.439 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7919.815000000
03-12 11:02:00.000 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7934.423000000
03-12 11:02:14.600 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7979.815000000
03-12 11:02:59.999 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 7994.455000000
03-12 11:03:14.639 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 8039.814000000
03-12 11:03:19.129 E/ActivityThread(814): Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.helphub.provider
03-12 11:03:19.889 E/ActivityThread(814): Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.helphub.provider
03-12 11:03:59.990 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 8054.481000000
03-12 11:04:14.649 E/AlarmManagerService(379): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 8099.814000000
```

Comment: This is not a proper question. you should also show these errors with your code, or what you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add what were you doing and how you get here.

Comment: I am no developer... No emulator. just using my android phone. I just want to know what can cause this problem. It just pops up unlimited times on my catlog app. 
and also on debug level this (D/FastDormancy(724): getDormancyFlag() return mDormFlag = true) message pops up like 6 times a second. what does these mean?? no help on searching google.. may be some site recommendations/tutorial which focuses on these area..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used com.samsung.helphub.provider, which is not found by emulator

Comment: May be some application used that.. and the emulator is my android phone